# -는데서 verb ending in 문화어

Tags: north-korean

I tried to find any usages of -는데서 conjugation form in South Korean, which seems to mean "in order to do something", but as I see, it isn't used in South (and it completely differs from -는데 or -는 데).

By the way, I find many cases in northern version, e.g. 불후의 고전적명작 《피바다》를 영화로 완성하는데서 나서는 몇가지 문제.

Is this form used in everyday speech in DPRK? Is it used anywhere in South Korea? What it actually means?

Comment: In south Korea, at ... 영화로 완성하는 데서 나서는 몇가지 ... , 오는, 생기는 are more suitable instead of 나서는.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't tell about North Korean, but "-는 데서" is commonly used in South Korea.  You might have missed it because in South Korea it is written with a space: 데 is a noun (의존 명사) meaning "place" or "thing(?)". 서 is just short for "-에서".

And you are right, they are completely different from verb suffix "-는데".

Here are some random sentences I found around the web.  Here, 데서 can be replaced by 것에서 without change of meaning:

> 공연은 [무대 위에 광주의 축소판을 구현하는 **데]서 시작한다.**
>
> = The performance **begins with** setting up a miniature Gwangju on the stage.
>
> [현재를 부정하는 **데]서 오는** 폭발적인 상상력, SF의 매력이죠
>
> = The charm of SF is explosive imagination **coming from** denying the present.
>
> 이 방식은 [하나의 케이블에 복수의 호스트를 연결하는 **데]서 발생하는** 많은 문제를 해소하였습니다.
>
> This method solved many problems **that arose from** connecting multiple hosts with a single cable.

A more informal example using "-는 데" (where you can't use 것):

> 내일 운동하는 데로 나와. = Come to the place where [we] work out, tomorrow.
>
> 점심은 맨날 먹는 데서 먹자. = Let's eat lunch where we eat it every day (i.e., at the usual place).

Comment: 점심은 맨날 먹는 데서 먹자. Why 맨날, not 매날?

Comment: Well, 맨날 is a word, and there's no word 매날. Actually, Naver dictionary says 맨날 has the same meaning as 만날, which is 萬날... although I don't think anybody says "만날" these days.